# My Python isn't reading the XML correctly

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

Here is my python code accessing the XML file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def display_book(book):

    root = ET.parse(source="library.xml")

    info = root.iter("catalog")

    for elem in info:
        name = elem.find("book").attrib['id']

        if name == book:
            print(name)

    return "Book Not Found"

#Main
display_book("bk105")
```

Here is a sample of the XML code:

```
<catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <description>
              An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.
        </description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <description>
              A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress,                         
              and her own childhood to become queen of the world.
        </description>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

The books go from "bk101" through "bk112" and the code is only finding the id of "bk101" as the first book and not iterating through every single book id and cross referencing it with the input so the program never outputs anything. Not even "Book Not Found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elem.find("book")` only returns the first book in the catalog. You need to use `elem.findall("book")`, and then iterate over them.

But you could just use `root.iter("book")` to iterate over the books directly.

```
for elem in root.iter("book"):
    name = elem.attrib('id')
    if name == book:
        print(name)
else:
    print("Book not found")
```

You should also put the error message in the `else:` block. Otherwise it will be returned even if the book is found.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to use `findall`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def display_book():

    root = ET.parse(source="library.xml")

    info = root.iter("catalog")

    for elem in info:
        books = elem.findall("book")
        for book in books:
            print book.attrib['id']


# Main
display_book()
```